Chances Of Same Random Number Selection Over An Exponentially Growing Set
If I pick at random number every second from a set of numbers that starts as the set {1->10^100} and then doubles in size every second for 1,000 seconds, what are the chances I will pick the same two numbers twice during that period?
What about 1,000,000 seconds?
What about 1,000,000,000 seconds?
What about 1,000,000,000,000 seconds?
What does the probability tend to as the number of seconds tends to infinity?
I'm asking because I don't believe what I keep hearing physicists say, which is that if the Multiverse (created by eternal inflation and containing infinite observable Universes like ours) is infinite then it's guaranteed that there are infinite "observable Universes" with planets with a carbon copy of me doing the same thing as me, right now.  I think they may be missing the crucial concept of the infinite size of the possibility space for each "observable Universe", which then allows things not to have to repeat.  If the answer to the above mathematical question is a very low probability, and it tends to zero as the number of seconds tends to infinity, then I feel this may back up my sense that the physicists could be wrong.   You could then try to map the numbers in the above scenario onto the number of possible combinations of atoms in each "observable Universe" and then ask what the probability of finding two identical universes are in the infinite set of universes.  The answer could be "almost zero".  Maybe I'm asking the wrong question?  Thoughts...?

This goes back at least to Nietsche c. 1865 and his theory of Eternal Recurrence.  It is incorrect to conclude "it's guaranteed that there are infinite "observable Universes" with planets with a carbon copy of me doing the same thing as me, right now" based on such a probability argument, regardless of what the mathematical answer to your probability question might be.  (The conclusion requires an ergodic assumption.) Thus, I would suggest this thread won't be satisfactory for you and you might be better off posing your underlying question in [Philosophy.se].

I agree with whuber that this is better posed to Philosophy

@whuber Thanks for the suggestion. I agree that the main point of my question is more mathematically philosophical so I will post it on the Philosophy group.  If we just stick to the first paragraph that is the actual question, that has 3 exact numerical answers and (if possible) an answer for what number the answer tends to. Isn't answering that and providing the method of calculation a pure maths  question?

It is, but it doesn't answer the underlying physical or philosophical questions at all.

Since your probability problem is very specific, and others might want to use different numbers and growth rates, I am going to generalise to solve a broader problem looking at the probability of distinct elements in selection from growing sets.  Let $0 < s_1 \leqslant s_2 \leqslant s_3 \leqslant \cdots$ be a sequence of non-decreasing positive set sizes and assume that $s_k \geqslant k$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ (i.e., the set size is never smaller than its place in the sequence).  Now define the sequence of independent random variables $X_1,X_2,X_3,...$ with respective distributions:
$$X_n \sim \text{U} \{ 1,...,s_n \},$$
and denote the resulting set sizes of distinct selections by:
$$M_n \equiv | \{ X_1,...,X_n \} |.$$
The event of interest is that there are no matches over the sequence (i.e., all the selections in the sequence are distinct), which is the event:
$$\mathscr{D} \equiv \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \{ M_n = n \}.$$

Finding the probability of interest: To facilitate analysis, define the sequence of nested events:
$$\mathscr{D}_k \equiv \bigcap_{n=1}^k \{ M_n = n \}.$$
We have the conditional probability:
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(\mathscr{D}_{k+1}| \mathscr{D}_k)
&= \mathbb{P}(\mathscr{D}_{k+1}| \mathscr{D}_k, X_{k+1} \leqslant s_k) \cdot \mathbb{P}(X_{k+1} \leqslant s_k) + \mathbb{P}(\mathscr{D}_{k+1}| \mathscr{D}_k, X_{k+1} > s_k) \cdot \mathbb{P}(X_{k+1} > s_k) \\[12pt]
&= \frac{s_k-k}{s_k} \cdot \frac{s_k}{s_{k+1}} + 1 \cdot \frac{s_{k+1} - s_k}{s_{k+1}} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{s_k-k}{s_{k+1}} + \frac{s_{k+1} - s_k}{s_{k+1}} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{s_{k+1} - k}{s_{k+1}}. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$
Since $\mathbb{P}(\mathscr{D}_1) = 1$ we then have:
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(\mathscr{D})
= \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}(\mathscr{D}_k)
&= \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \prod_{i=1}^{k-1} \mathbb{P}(\mathscr{D}_{i+1} | \mathscr{D}_i) \\[6pt]
&= \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \prod_{i=1}^{k-1} \bigg( 1 - \frac{i}{s_{i+1}} \bigg) \\[6pt]
&= \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} \bigg( 1 - \frac{i}{s_{i+1}} \bigg). \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

In your particular problem you have $s_i = 10^{100} \cdot 2^{i-1}$ so you have:
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(\mathscr{D})
&= \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} \bigg( 1 - \frac{i}{s_{i+1}} \bigg) \\[6pt]
&= \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} \bigg( 1 - 10^{-100} \cdot \frac{i}{2^i} \bigg). \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

This is incomplete without some sense of its magnitude.  The analysis is fairly easy: take logarithms and expand each term up to second order in $z = 2^{-1}$ as an analytic function, thereby obtaining a lower bound.

@whuber: Yes, I ran out of puff yesterday since I'm doing a walking challenge for work.  I'll come back to this and finish it in a day or two.

@Ben Thanks for the answer and looking forward to the completed version
